# Ruby: Replace parts of a string

Tags: ruby, regex, string, replace

I have many strings following a certain pattern:

```
string = "Hello, @name. You did @thing." # example
```

Basically, my strings are a description where @word is dynamically. I need to replace each with a value at runtime.

```
string = "Hello, #{@name}. You did #{@thing}." # Is not an option!
```

The @word is basically a variable, but I just cannot use the method above.
How should I do that?

Comment: Try searching for it - use this: `[ruby] replace string hash`. The solution can be as simple (one-two inline expressions) or as complex (template library) as desired.

Answer (score 13):

Instead doing search/replace, you can use [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Kernel%3asprintf) method, or its `%` shorthand. Combined with Hashes, it can come pretty handy:

```
'Hello, %{who}. You did %{what}' % {:who => 'Sal', :what => 'wrong'}
# => "Hello, Sal. You did wrong"
```

The advantage of using Hash instead of Array is that you don't have to worry about the ordering, and you can have the same value inserted on multiple places in the string.

Comment: Wow, I've never known about this! Ruby is still a surprise for me after 5 years! Thanks a lot for this answer!

Answer (score 6):

You can format your string with placeholders that can be switched out dynamically using String's [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25) operator.

```
string = "Hello, %s. You did %s"

puts string % ["Tony", "something awesome"]
puts string % ["Ronald", "nothing"]

#=> 'Hello, Tony. You did something awesome'
#=> 'Hello, Ronald. You did nothing'
```

**Possible use case:** Let's say you were writing a script that would be taking the name and action in as parameters.

```
puts "Hello, %s. You did %s" % ARGV
```

Assuming 'tony' and 'nothing' were the first two parameters, you would get `'Hello, Tony. You did nothing'`.

Comment: And this looks way simpler! :)